# Django Model Authorisation

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django app, I've some CRUD operations over some models, which I want to be accessed only by the user who created that row. Here it's not role based authorisation as all users are same, I want them to be identified by the user who created it.

I tried something like:

```
class someModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True)
    ....
```

In my views, I would do the checking by:

```
def view(request, id):
    model = somemodel.objects.get(id=id, user=request.user)
    if model.user = request.user:
    ...
```

Would this be the easiest and yet be the correct way to do row level authorisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the views that need to check if the use is authenticated can have the login_required decorator. Then you can use try, except instead of if else because that's more pythonic

```
@login_required
def view(request, id):
    try:
        model = somemodel.objects.get(id=id, user=request.user) #this will raise an exception if not found
    except Somemodel.DoesnotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

This of course begins to look boiler plate like. That's where Class Based Views come into the picture. Alternatively you can reduce the boiler plate code  with

```
@login_required
def view(request, id):
    my_object = get_object_or_404(SomeModel, pk=1, user=request.user)
    # get_object_or_404 also throws a MultipleObjectsReturned exception                  
    # when more then one object is returned, so catch it if needed.
```

Comment: Can you help me out with class-based example of this?

Comment: That's a bit broad, how about the get_object_or_404 solution that I just updated the answer with (before seeing your comment)

Comment: The initial work of Class Based Views approach is a lot more

Answer (score 0):

You can even reduce one line of checking `if model.user = request.user:` as you already filtered the data with the logged in user in `model = somemodel.objects.get(id=id, user=request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

```
class getUserData(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        userName = request.data['userName']

        try:
            checkUserLoggedIn = YourAuthenticationModel.objects.get(id=id, user=userName)

            getRow = someModel.objects.filter(user=userName)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print "User does not exist or logged In"
```